# Why doesn't the browser redirect to sign-inpage, when we add parameters to the Url?

Tags: c#, php, redirect, http-status-code-302, webview2

I'm working on an add-in for Outlook from Ms Office. Basically we have integrated a part of our web application in Outlook by using a **Webview2** in C#.Net (this used to be a **WebBrowser** control). The problem I'm having, is that the page should redirect to the sign-in page if the user is not signed in. But it doesn't, at least not when we use the complete link. The page does not redirect, and we get a **302** response.

Let's say we try to connect to example.com/index.php?page=settings&action=edit, we would be redirected to example.com/login.php That's actually working fine.

But we're adding parameters to let the browser know we're working with Outlook. so example.com/index.php?page=settings&action=edit&compact=true&outlookVersionCode=2&outlookVersion=1.0.1

This doesn't work. It has worked before, back when we used the WebBrowser control, which uses Internet Explorer. Now we replaced it with a WebView, which's rendering engine is Edge (Chromium).

Even when we just add "compact=true", it doesn't redirect. I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and it all gave the same result.

Edit: In Internet Explorer it somehow works just fine.

Kind regards,
Dries

Comment: Please post the code of your index.php (in particular the parts on redirection and processing of the REQUEST variables ---  in your case the $_GET variables)

Comment: It turns out there was actually a check against these parameters in the url. I suspect that the reason the redirect happened in Internet Explorer is due to a bug in IE.
Thank you for your time!